# How do I prevent Material UI from desaturating the colour of my AppBar when my theme is in dark mode?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

Using `mode: "dark"` in my Material UI theme desaturates the colour of my AppBar.
Switching it to `mode: "light"` stops this issue from occurring.

My theme is setup like this:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        mode: "dark",
        primary: {
            main: "#1c7eea"
        }
    }
});
```

My AppBar is created like this:

```
<AppBar position="sticky" enableColorOnDark>
```

[This image shows how the AppBar appears in light mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyVSh.png)

[This image shows how the AppBar appears in dark mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvXU1.png)

I've been looking all over the documentation and through the Material UI code to see if I can find out why this is happening, or how to prevent it, but haven't managed to find a solution.

No other elements have their colours desaturated in this manner, it is only the AppBar.

---

**Edit:** A solution I have found is to set the `background` CSS property manually like this:

```
<AppBar position="sticky" sx={{ background: "#1c7eea" }} enableColorOnDark>
```

While this solution works, I still don't see why this is necessary, why is Material UI desaturating my primary theme colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another customized palette for the dark theme like so:

```js
const getDesignTokens = (mode: PaletteMode) => ({
  palette: {
    mode,
    ...(mode === 'light'
      ? {
          // palette values for light mode
          primary: amber,
          divider: amber[200],
          text: {
            primary: grey[900],
            secondary: grey[800],
          },
        }
      : {
          // palette values for dark mode
          primary: deepOrange,
          divider: deepOrange[700],
          background: {
            default: deepOrange[900],
            paper: deepOrange[900],
          },
          text: {
            primary: '#fff',
            secondary: grey[500],
          },
        }),
  },
});
```

Check full explanation here https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/

UPDATED on October 5h, 2022

I inspected and noticed that the AppBar (Paper) component adds an overlay to  it when in dark mode. You can do a workaround by adding the following inline css to the AppBar component and overriding that behavior, like so:

```js
<AppBar position="sticky" style={{backgroundImage: "none"}} >
  Dark
</AppBar>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem though. My point is that I would like to have the same primary colour for both light and dark themes, which is what I've got set up.

The issue is that the AppBar colour gets desaturated and I can't see why that is happening, especially given that this doesn't happen to any other components.

Comment: It's because you don't have a dark theme. Follow the directions and make sure you have a dark theme implemented, otherwise, Material UI will modify your colors. If you want the same colors, just repeat them in both themes.

Comment: Do you mean adding `dark` and `light` properties to `palette.primary`? If so, I have tried that too, but the AppBar colour still gets desaturated for some reason.

Comment: You are right, I've just updated my response with a workaround for this.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! Your updated solution works like a charm, I greatly appreciate it.